# An analytic method to prove a specific curve is closed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, curves

In my study of Hamiltonian dynamics I have come across a Hamiltonian dynamic system with a solution curve I know to be closed via computer and via intuition but I require a rigorous way to prove this, the problem simply is:

> We have the curve in $\mathbb{R}^2 $ described via the equation $\sin(x)\sin(\pi y)=1/2 $ (of course for single period of the sines as they are periodic so this equation can describe infinitely many curves). We are to show this curve is closed. The Hamiltonian is $ H(x,y)=\sin(x)\sin(\pi y) $

My intuition was regarding periodicity of the sines.
My purpose is basically to show it is not a limit cycle but a closed orbit in phase space, so can someone please demonstrate rigorously why this curve is closed? I have the intuition but not the right rigorous ideas. I thank all helpers.

Comment: Do you know about morse theory?

Comment: Maybe writing out the Hamiltonian and explaining your intuition will help a bit.

Comment: @Timkinsella I do not know Morse theory

Comment: Actually, sorry, its not so much morse theory.  Do you know that pre images of regular values of a smooth function are imbedded sub manifolds of codimension 1?

Comment: @Timkinsella no sorry I do not know about this

Comment: No worries.  I see you're an undergrad studying geometry and topology.  You should definitely check out the great book "differential topology" by Guillemin and Pollock.

Comment: A little bit of that book gives a nice solution to your problem:  $f(x,y)= \sin(x)\sin(\pi y)$ is a smooth function and $1/2$ is one of its regular values (this just means the derivative of $f$ is surjective at every point $f$ maps to $1/2$).  This implies that $f^{-1}(1/2)$ is an imbedded sub manifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  If you can show that there exist no solutions on the boundary of a box around one of the solutions, then inside that box the solution set must consist of a finite union of imbedded 1-submanifolds.  Now 1-submanifolds are either homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or $S^1$.

Comment: (the classification of 1-manifolds is also done in Guillemin and Pollock). Since the solution set is closed and we are confined to a bounded subset of the plane, its not hard to see we cannot have homeomorphs of $\mathbb{R}$.  This means the solution set in this region must be a finite union of homeomorphs of circles.

Comment: Can't you simply investigate what the graph $y=\frac{1}{\pi}\arcsin\frac{1}{2\sin x}$ looks like? (It is one solution of your equation, and all the other solutions can be expressed in terms of this one too.)